# dependency error in android studio= com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+

Tags: android-studio

I am getting this dependency error in Android Studio, how can I fix it?

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Don&#39;t U DArE/AndroidStudioProjects/1stApp/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.">Show Details</a>   
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Don&#39;t U DArE/AndroidStudioProjects/1stApp/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.">Show Details</a>    
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Don&#39;t U DArE/AndroidStudioProjects/1stApp/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.">Show Details</a>   
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Don&#39;t U DArE/AndroidStudioProjects/1stApp/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@release/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.">Show Details</a> 
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Don&#39;t U DArE/AndroidStudioProjects/1stApp/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.">Show Details</a>
```

Comment: have you just pasted the error without any explanation?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I strongly recommend you to read the article [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question will have way more chance to find an answer.

Comment: Use the [edit] button to add more information and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use support library version `29` but there is no such version. The latest version is `28.0.0`, see [Recent Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions).

You need to migrate your support library to AndroidX. See [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).